# mysql process stuck "sending data" state and hangs

Tags: mysql, performance

on some time interval mysql stuck with too many process in state "sending data" have already optimized query and increased max connection but still not working

[show process list result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKAxr.png)

Comment: From the image, looks like it is multiple instances of the same query stuck in "sending data". Can you share the `EXPLAIN` associated with that query?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information to analyze your specific case. I would troubleshoot the problem w/ the following order.

1. Use `EXPLAIN` before each query and analyze the output, do you need to scan a lot of rows in any specific step? Do you have any key entry with `NULL` in it?
2. Based on (1), decide on simplifying the query or add an index to large tables.
3. Start investigating the integrity of the database. Investigate if you have any corrupted tables.
4. Investigate the underlying system (memory, CPU, and IO). [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/207610) can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `JOIN languges ON ...`; it wastes time without providing any information other than verifying that the languge has an entry there.

If you wish to discuss further, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query in text form, not image.